# numpy.fromregex with caret (match to the start of the string)

Tags: python, regex, numpy

How can I match the beginning of a line using `numpy.fromregex`?

I'm trying to use `numpy.fromregex` on a collection of log files which include both 'training' metrics and 'validation' metrics. These metrics appear on identical lines except that the validation metrics begin with the word 'TEST':

```
dat 1 dat 2 ... # training
TEST dat 1 dat 2 ... # validation
```

When I use the caret `^` to match the beginning of the line (to extract training metrics), I get no matches:

```
r'dat \d+ dat \d+' # matches all lines
r'^dat \d+ dat \d+' # matches zero lines
```

I've even tried a pattern like `^.*dat 1`, which should match all of the lines, but it returns zero matches. I've also tried `\A` in place of `^`, but its results are the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fromregex` doesn't do a line-by-line search. It applies the regex to the entire file contents at once, so `^` only matches at the start of the whole file.

If you precompile your regex with the `re.MULTILINE` flag, `^` will match at the start of each line.