# Numpy fromregex - ValueError

Tags: python, regex, numpy

I am struggling with the numpy command `fromregex`. In particular with the `dtype`keyword.

I need to parse a file which lines look like this

`"Aaron",2020,"m"`.

The regexp to match the year is simply `r',([0-9]+),'`. The **final array** should contain strings only. The grouping is fundamental since it will become a field of the array.

At the moment I got a working example but the final array contain integers.

*Array of integers*

```
import numpy as np

path = ''# location of the dataset

regex = r',([0-9]+),'

data = np.fromregex(file=path, regexp=regex, dtype=[('yr', np.dtype('i'))])
data = np.fromregex(file=path, regexp=regex, dtype=[('yr', np.int_)])
```

Output (for both)

```
[2011 2020 2009 ... 2018 2018 2017]
```

*Attempt with string*  `np.dtype`

```
regex = r',([0-9]+),'

try:
    data = np.fromregex(file=path, regexp=regex, dtype=[('yr', np.str_)])
except ValueError as e:
    print(e)
try:
    data = np.fromregex(file=path, regexp=regex, dtype=[('yr', np.dtype('U'))])
except ValueError as e:
    print(e)
```

Output (for both): `ValueError`

```
When changing to a smaller dtype, its size must be a divisor of the size of original dtype
```

I tried also with `np.dtype('O')` (python object) and `np.dtype('V')` (void) with no success.

Furthermore, how does the command do the match? line per line? **EDIT:** see comment below

Here the docs for [fromregex](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.fromregex.html)

Some *entries of the dataset*

```
"Abby",2014,"w"
"Abby",2010,"w"
"Abby (Abbygail)",2013,"w"
"Abel",2020,"m"
"Abenaki Dakil",2016,"m"
"Abraxa",2007,"w"
```

Comment: for the question "how does the command do the match? line per line?" I found the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51730850/numpy-fromregex-with-caret-match-to-the-start-of-the-string : "fromregex doesn't do a line-by-line search. It applies the regex to the entire file contents at once, so ^ only matches at the start of the whole file." [so for example]
"If you precompile your regex with the re.MULTILINE flag, ^ will match at the start of each line."

Comment: With a compound dtype (structured array), the string length has to be explicit.  It can't/won't deduce it from the data. e.g.` dtype=[('yr', np.dtype('U10'))]`

Comment: @hpaulj Is this due to memory pre-allocation? With your advise it works even with `dtype=[('yr', np.dtype('U4'))]' . What can I do if the entries in a column are not of homogeneous length? How can I find/estimate a good upper-bound? i.e. if we switch to the 1st column then by brute force I find out that the upper bound is 'U15'...

Comment: `np.array(['one','two','three'])` processes the whole list, checking for the longest string, and setting `dtype` accordingly.  `fromregex` does `np.array(seq, dtype=dtype)` where `seq` comes from the `re` `findall`, and should be a list of tuples.  This is standard structured array creation.  The `dtype` determines how many bytes are allocated for each record, without any attempt to adjust for the length of strings in tuples.

Comment: @hpaulj thanks! I was trying to find an alternative way to numpy loadfile. My conclusion: if data homogeneous fromregex ok otherwise, for example, loadfile. You answer to my question, thanks! [you can put it as answer...]